# Call a Swift function with completion handler from Java Script (TVML)

Tags: javascript, swift, tvos, tvml

I'm working on tvOS app (using TVML) and I'm trying to call a Swift function with completion handler from JS.

In the TVApplicationControllerDelegate I try with code like this:

```
let getVastData : @convention(block) (String,  @escaping (UInt32, [String], String) -> ()) -> Void = {
    (url : String, _ completion:@escaping (_ duration: UInt32, _ addLinks: [String], _ videoLink: String) -> ()) -> Void in
    VastManager.shared.startParsing(with: url, completion)
}

jsContext.setObject(unsafeBitCast(getVastData, to: AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "getVastData" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)!)
```

but I'm geting error: "TypeError: getVastData is not a function. (In 'getVastData', 'getVastData' is an instance of NSBlock"

Do you know where I'm wrong or how to correct call Swift func with completion handler from JS?

Thanks in advance,
Milos

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to register our Swift method in jsContext. Our Swift method needs to accept callback function, in our case a reference to a JavaScipt value which will be called after our operations in Swift are finished.

```
let getVastData : @convention(block) (String, JSValue) -> Void = {
    (url : String, completion : JSValue) -> Void in
    VastManager.shared.startParsing(from: url, completion: completion)
}
jsContext.setObject(unsafeBitCast(getVastData, to: AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "getVastData" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol))
```

Because we want to call it asynchronously we need to store that reference. We will use JSManagedValue for storing JSValue to avoid retain cycle. A JSManagedValue object wraps a JSValue object, adding "conditional retain" behavior to provide automatic memory management of values. After our operations are finished, we can call our JavaScript callback function back with arguments. Briefly, we just passed the JS value from our TVML JS to Swift, store it and call it later.

```
class VastManager: NSObject {

    var completion: JSManagedValue?
    var url: String?

    public func startParsing(from url: String, completion: JSValue) {
        self.completion = JSManagedValue(value: completion)
        self.url = url
    }
    ...

    func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {

        ...

        _ = self.completion?.value?.call(withArguments: [duration, ads, videoUrl])
    }
}
```

In the end, we can call our Swift function from JavaScript and pass our callback function.

```
getVastData(vastTag, function(duration, adLinks, videoLink) {
   ...
}
// or
function updatePlayer(duration, adLinks, videoLink) {
   ...
}
getVastData(vastTag, updatePlayer) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you invoke your completion handler inside your ```evaluate(inJavaScriptContext:)``` block? Simply doing ```completion.call(withArguments:)``` seems to work just fine in my app.

Comment: @Anders Your approach is better/simpler, I will update my comment.

Comment: Another comment: I'm not sure if you should store a non-managed ```JSValue``` as it *can* create a retain cycle. Instead, you might be better off changing your ```completion``` property to a ```JSManagedValue```. I'm not completely sure of your setup, but have a look at the documentation and decide if it's relevant in your use case:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jsmanagedvalue

Comment: @Anders. You are right, I changed completion to JSManagedValue. I didn't have problems with the old solution but this will probably prevent some future bugs.

Comment: @MilosMokic @anders i'm pretty sure that this is wrong. JSManagedValue alone just prevents retain cycle from JSValue and JSContext (which can be resolved by putting the JSValue back to nil after calling the block anyway). If you instead just use JSManagedValue you are just storing a weak reference to the JSValue, and in the first option where you create a callback function on the spot, no one is holding a strong ref to that. So it will get deallocated. If you want to use JSManagedValue you also have to call `addManagedReference(_:withOwner:)` to keep the strong ref on the actual value in JS.